# Pear System daemon mysql_connect error

Tags: php, mysql, pear

I have created a daemon using the PHP PEAR System Daemon Script. I call mysql_query within the Daemon script, but I get the error PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

I'm guessing that I need to include a file that will allow for the daemon to recognize mysql_connect, but I already include PHP at the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
```

Shouldn't that be enough?

Here's the beginning code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
require_once "System/Daemon.php";

System_Daemon::setOption("appName", "test");
System_Daemon::start();

$runningOkay = true;

while(!System_Daemon::isDying() && $runningOkay){

$runningOkay = true;

$connect = mysql_connect('.....')

if(!$connect) ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the config file (`php.ini`) used by the PHP command line does not enable the mysql extension.

Run

```
/usr/bin/php -i | grep ini
```

to find the config file in use then modify it to enable the extension. This usually just involves uncommenting the relevant line.